# Xamarin forms, putting a listview inside a relative or absolute layout in a tabbedPage

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a setup in my app where I use a TabbedPage and in that I have a page with a listView.
In order to show an ActivityIndicator, I use the approach where I put the listView inside an AbsoluteLayout.
However, this has the sad effect that the last items in my listview are out of reach. I can't scroll to them properly.
I think this has to do with the sizing of the Absolute layout but I can't make it good.

Is there another solution to getting activity indicators or can it be corrected? Should I use a relative layout instead?

Instead of setting the Content property, I use this method:

```
protected void SetContent (View content)
    {
        var overlay = new AbsoluteLayout ();
        loadingIndicator = new ActivityIndicator {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            Scale = 2,
            Color = Color.Silver
        };
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags (content, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds (content, new Rectangle (0f, 0f, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags (loadingIndicator, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds (loadingIndicator, new Rectangle (0.5, 0.5, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));
        overlay.Children.Add (content);
        overlay.Children.Add (loadingIndicator);
        Content = overlay;
    }
```

in my pages inside the TabbedPage.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use [ACR UserDialogs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/)

```
using (this.Dialogs.Loading("Test Loading"))
    await Task.Delay(3000);
```

Initialization

iOS and Windows

Nothing is necessary any longer as of v4.x.  There is an Init function for iOS but it is OPTIONAL and only required if you want/need to control
the top level viewcontroller for things like iOS extensions.  Progress prompts will not use this factory function though!

Android (in MainActivity.cs)

```
UserDialogs.Init(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the `Grid` control as well. Whenever you set two elements inside the same row, they'll overlap each other correctly. So, basically you would have one or more rows with all your page content and then on the bottom of the page, you'd define the `ActivityIndicator` and set it to the row 0. Depending on the number of rows, you'd need to set the `RowSpacing`to something other than 1 so that it covers the whole page.

By doing this, you make sure that the `ActivityIndicator` is on top of all the controls (the ones on the bottom of XAML are the ones on the top in runtime). Obviously, the same thing works on code-behind too.